# PyGreSQL is returning unexpected result for a one column select statement

Tags: python, python-db-api, pygresql

I have the following PostgreSQL database table:

```
TABLE session_monitor
(
    id int,
    customer_name varchar(150)
)
```

When I am running the following code:

```py
seq = pg_cur.execute("SELECT id ,customer_name from session_monitor")
for id, customer_name in seq:
    print(id)
    print(customer_name)
```

it is working fine.

But when I try

```py
pg_cur.execute("SELECT max(id) as max_id from session_monitor")
for max_id in seq:
    print(max_id)
```

I am not getting a number, but rather: `Row(max_id= 5)`

I tried a workaround that sort of solves the problem:

```py
seq = pg_cur.execute("SELECT max(id) as max_id,1 as one from session_monitor")
for max_id, one in seq:
    print(max_id)
```

but it seems kind of lame to use it like this.

What am I doing wrong here - is there a different way to iterate the query result in the second case?

Comment: I took the liberty to format your code a bit nicer. You should put code snippets inside three backticks instead of two asterisks to make them more readable. Also added python and db-api tags since this is not pygresql specific.

Answer (score 2):

You get this result due to the way how DB API 2 works (it returns tuples for rows from the database), combined with the Python quirk that you need to add a comma when you want to specify a tuple with one element. It has little to do with PyGreSQL.

So, when you first do this, you get a sequence of (named) tuples in `seq`:

```py
seq = cur.execute("SELECT id, customer_name FROM session_monitor")
```

When you then do the following, you iterate over that sequence *while unpacking* the row tuple you get in each iteration to `id` and `customer_name`:

```py
for id, customer_name in seq:
    print(id)
    print(customer_name)
```

When you only select one column, like this, you *still* get a sequence of (named) tuples, with only one element per tuple:

```py
seq = cur.execute("SELECT max(id) AS max_id FROM session_monitor")
```

Now you tried to iterate over the sequence like this:

```py
for max_id in seq:
    print(max_id)
```

The difference to the loop above is that this one *does no tuple unpacking*. So `max_id` will be the complete row, which is printed.

To make use of tuple unpacking like above, you need to add a comma after the `max_id`:

```py
for max_id, in seq:
    print(max_id)
```

This will print what you expected. Btw, you can also add parens around the tuple unpacking expression. However, you still need a comma if a tuple only has one element.

Of course, if you only get one row with one column, you could just do:

```py
seq = cur.execute("SELECT max(id) AS max_id FROM session_monitor")
max_id = list(seq)[0][0]
print(max_id)
```

Or, alternatively, using the `fetchone()` method:

```py
cur.execute("SELECT max(id) as max_id FROM session_monitor")
max_id = cur.fetchone()[0]
print(max_id)
```

And of course, you can also make use of the fact that you get named tuples:

```py
cur.execute("SELECT max(id) as max_id from session_monitor")
print(cur.fetchone().max_id)
```

As a side note, using the "classic" PyGreSQL interface instead of DB API 2, you would do this:

```py
q = db.query('SELECT max(id) FROM session_monitor')
print(q.singlescalar())
```

The `single()` method gets a single row like `fetchone()`, and `singlescalar()` gets the first column of that row.

Comment: Thanks so much for the very detailed explain.